# keras.module.load_model raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', 'group')

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi

I allow myself to post a thread on this community and hope it will help me and other as well. I've been searching for over 5 hours now; have scraped the entire Google search engine first pages without any results, despite my motivation to fix the issue.

Basically, I used Google Colab to train my model. It went really well. I've printed as well the different version of keras and tensorflow which looks like this :

```
#Printed from Google Colab training model
tf.__version__: 2.6.0
keras.__version__: 2.6.0
```

Then, when running/loading my model on my Raspberry Pi 4, I'm getting the following error.

```
2021-08-25 16:39:11.593011: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] 
HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#Printed from Raspberry Pi 4
tf.__version__: 1.14.0
keras.__version__: 2.2.4-tf
INFO:root:Creating a DeepLearningLaneFollower...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeepLearningFollower.py", line 151, in <module>
    test_video('/home/pi/Desktop/PyLot_COPY/4-deep-learning/video01')
  File "DeepLearningFollower.py", line 109, in test_video
    end_to_end_lane_follower = DeepLearningLaneFollower()
  File "DeepLearningFollower.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.model = load_model('lane_navigation_final.h5', compile = False)  ## force keras 
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py",     line 146, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 168, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 106, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 274, in     deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 377, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 106, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 276, in     deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 616, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 503, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 122, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 296, in __init__
    generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 682, in validate_kwargs
    raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups')
```

As you can see, my version of tensorflow and keras differ from Google Colab. I've read many threads about this. I've tried with desperation to upgrade it, however python refuses to admit that a version of tensorflow above 2 exists (even with the activation of an environment).

Does anyone have a solution or idea where exactly my issue comes from and how to solve it ?

Comment: Your Tensorflow and Keras versions are different in Raspberry Pi and Colab. Try loading model with same Tensorflow version.

Comment: https://www.bitsy.ai/3-ways-to-install-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/ ?